# How to take specific value from key in JSON in Scala?

Tags: java, json, scala

I want to return the value `"stations"` from the key `"base"` in the JSON below from the url `https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22`. How do I do that in Scala?

Here is what I attempted.

```
import scalaj.http._
import play.api.libs.json.{JsValue, Json}

object JSON {
def convertToJson(): String = {
    val url: String = "https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22"
    val response: String = Http(url).asString.body
    val parsed: JsValue = Json.parse(response)
    parsed.get(base)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `\` method returning a property corresponding a field name

`val result: JsLookupResult = parsed \ "base"`

If you want the result as string you can use `as[String]` conversion

`println(result.as[String])`

It will print "station", but it can throw an exception if it isn't really String

In case if value is missing you can use pattern matching:

```
result match {
  case JsDefined(v) => println(v.toString) // will print "stations"
  case undefined: JsUndefined => println(undefined.validationError) // prints error in case missing value
}
```